# SharePoint site associated groups are not returned in code after owner change

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I've created a site collection and its associated groups (owners, members and visitors) and associated the site collection admin as their owner. I then tried to get them using powershell and it worked fine.

Then, I changed the associated groups owner to a different user (which is members of the owners associated group) and tried to get them through powershell but this time, it seems like sharepoint is not recognizing them :

[image]

Does anyone has an idea of what's going on and how to let sharepoint recognize them even if the group owner is not the site collection admin ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86940/what-is-the-effect-of-setting-spweb-associatedowner-member-visitorgroup

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions at "Set up groups" section of [this article at support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-SharePoint-groups-224A7F52-720F-4859-9695-FF09496A0791#bmsetupgroups).

**Or** you might try setting `$web`'s `AssociatedOwnerGroup`, `AssociatedMemberGroup` and `AssociatedVisitorGroup` manually in powershell

Also there is `SPWeb.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups` method to create completely new set of groups, just in case